# Should we remove the 'inventory' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should the [inventory](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inventory) tag be removed? Are there people who are experts at inventories?

As of writing this, there are 29 questions that use the tag, with only two of them closed, so there doesn't seem to be a major issue with the tag existing, but I'd just like to know if it's something that we should keep around.

Comment: I'm just about to program an inventory, so for this purpose I'd like the tag to stay.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not so sure we should get rid of it. Inventory related code and design problems are unique to games, and this tag provides scope and discoverability to that unique problem domain.

I *do* think it's possible to have expertise in implementing these kinds of systems and designs, so I don't think we should get rid of it.

---

This is probably opposite the stance I would have taken even a month ago, but in reviewing our catalogue of tags recently I've started to come around to the idea that we're too sterile in our handling of tags, increasingly sacrificing domain-specific tags on the alter of "can you be an expert" dogma that is perhaps part of the reason we have some seriously bloated catch-all tags like [game-design](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design).

Comment: I think we should keep the tag if a definition for it is made. Right now, it is rather vague

Comment: So would the [tag:inventory] tag need to come along with another tag such as [tag:architecture], [tag:data-structure] or [tag:game-design]?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Rather, I'm more thinking that the way we've decided to venerate tags like architecture, data-structure and game-design means we're trending towards having lots of big, open, basically-useless tags in favor of many smaller, domain-focused ones.

Answer (score 4):

I feel this is a meta tag.

The tag has no description, and no usage guidelines. Most of the questions with that tag could have either [data-structure](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-structure) or [user-experience](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-experience) instead.

Also, can one be an expert in inventory? I find it hard to believe.

I suggest we remove it and blacklist it.

Comment: I was surprised when editing a crafting question this morning that we have an inventory tag but not a crafting one. It seems to me more likely someone could be an expert in item transaction features than item storage features. ;)

Comment: @DMGregory It's probably another discussion topic, but would crafting be about the game design aspect, or the implementation?

Comment: Not sure. I don't think we need either tag — it just struck me as odd to find a question about crafting transactions tagged something as generic as inventory, so I agree, the inventory tag isn't doing any clarifying in situations like this.

Comment: [tag:gui] seems like a better alternative to me. [tag:data-structure] is more about data storage in code

Comment: @Bálint That would depend on the question asked.

Comment: I disagree that [tag:inventory] is a meta-tag. [tag:inventory] is about the content of the question and doesn't communicate any meta-information. Also, [tag:inventory] can be the only tag on a question, and it would be enough to give a general idea of what it is about.